# Grafana Prometheus merge two columns

Tags: merge, prometheus, grafana, promql

I use the sflow-rt-exporter (https://github.com/sflow-rt/prometheus) to collect my traffic on my switches.

I then created a Grafana table where I see the traffic seperated in "source", "destination" and "traffic".

Now I would like to create a table in which the columns "source" and "destination" are in one column. So that it doesn't matter if the traffic went from or to this server.

Example:

```
Source    | Destination | Traffic
123.4.5.6 | 234.5.6.7   | 200B
234.5.6.7 | 123.4.5.6   | 500B

should become

IP        | Traffic
123.4.5.6 | 700B
```

After a week of trying I finally give up and hope that one of you can help me :)

Thanks in advance.

Greetings
L1nk27

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to your request is that you want to aggregate on distinct dimensions (labels) which is not possible with Prometheus.

Therefore, you must create another dimension (let call it `IP`) to collect the sides (`source` and `destination)`. This can be done using the [label_replace](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#label_replace) function:

- This will copy `source` label into `IP`:

  ```
  label_replace(traffic, "IP", "$1", "source", "(.*)")
  ```
- This will copy `destination` label into `IP`:

  ```
  label_replace(traffic, "IP", "$1", "destination", "(.*)")
  ```

Note that that you cannot have duplicates as the original values are kept (this is important). Then you can use the [OR](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators) binary operator to concatenate them and then sum over the `IP` label:

```
sum by(IP) (
  label_replace(traffic, "IP", "$1", "source", "(.*)")
  OR
  label_replace(traffic, "IP", "$1", "destination", "(.*)"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the solution i searched.
I tried previously to use label_replace, but grafana wouldn't stop complaining. The binary OR operation seems to be the missing piece